# unable to link derby DB with my java app on netbeans

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

i've created a DB for an app project and i realised all the windows for the app and when i tried to link the derby DB to my project it doesn't work !! i've wrote couple of codes to link the DB but still doesn't work ( at first i worked with the data base i've created then i've tried to link the embedded DB to my project but nothing ) here what've tried !! did i missed something ?

```
  try {  Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
    Connection cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\\Users\\user pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\NetBeans\\Derby\\projetihm","root","root");
    Statement stm= cnx.createStatement();
    String qst = "Select * from ROOT.USERAPP where username='"+uname.getText()+"'";
    ResultSet rst = stm.executeQuery(qst);
    if (rst.next())
         { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connexion successful");
                 }
    else {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong password or username"); }
 }
 catch (Exception e ) {};
```

and i also tried this one

```
Try{  Connection cnx= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/projetihm","root","root");
Statement stm= cnx.newStatement();
ResultSet rst = stm.executeQuery("Select * From userapp ");
while (rst.next())
   if (rs.getString(1).equals(uname.getText()) && rst.getString(2).equals(pass.getText()))
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong password or username try again");
                 }
    else {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong password or username try again"); }
 }
 catch (Exception e ) {};
```

Comment: First, please replace`catch (Exception e) {}` with `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}` to see if there were any exceptions.

Comment: it says that the launch of the DB has failled but i have no idea what's the problem is it the url path or something else !!

Comment: Could you please add stack trace to your question?

Comment: it's okay i've solved it

Comment: i'll post the code i used in the question section

Comment: *"it's okay i've solved it ... i'll post the code i used in the question section"* - No, post it as an answer. Here on Stack Overflow it is quite acceptable for someone to answer their own question.

Comment: ahh thank you i didn't know i'm kinda new hhhhh

Answer (score 1):

i solved it like this, it works now !

```
try {   
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
    Connection cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/projetihm","root","root");
    Statement stm= cnx.createStatement();
    ResultSet rst = stm.executeQuery("Select * From userapp");
    while (rst.next())
       if (rst.getString(1).equals(uname.getText()) && rst.getString(4).equals(pass.getText()))
    {    this.setVisible(false);
        all a = new all(); a.setVisible(true);
             }
       else {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong password or username "); }

    } catch (Exception e) {  e.printStackTrace(); }
```